# Where is energy stored in a molecule of ATP?

Tags: photosynthesis

Where is energy stored in a molecule of ATP?

How is energy released from a molecule of ATP? What specific bond needs to break

What is the difference between ATP and ADP?

1. Define pigment

a.  What pigments are found in plants?

b.  What colors of the Visible Spectrum do chlorophyll pigments absorb? Not absorb?

c.  What would you expect to happen if a plant was grown under a green light? Blue or red light?

2. Label and define the following:

a.  Granum:

b.  Thylakoid:

c.  Stroma:

4a-3 Explain how photosynthetic organisms use the processes of photosynthesis – Ch. 8-3

3. Define autotroph, give an example
4. Define heterotroph, give an example
5. Define photosynthesis and write out the equation for photosynthesis (both the word equation and the chemical equation – you need to be able to recognize the chemical equation)
6. What are the three factors that affect the rate of photosynthesis, and how does their absence or presence affect the rate?
7. 
8. 
9. 
10. The rate at which a plant carries out photosynthesis depends in part on its environment. Plants that grow in the shade, for example, carry out photosynthesis at low levels of light. Plants that grow in the sun, such as desert plants, typically carry out photosynthesis at much higher levels of light. 
    The graph below compares the rates of photosynthesis between plants that grow in the shade and plants that grow in the sun. It shows how the rate of photosynthesis changes with the number of micromoles of photons per square meter per second (μmol photons/m2/s), a standard unit of light intensity.

a.

When light intensity is below 200 μmol photons/m2/s, do sun plants or shade plants have a higher rate of photosynthesis?

b.  Does the relationship in question 1 change when light intensity increases above 400 μmol photons/m2/s? Explain your answer.

c.  The average light intensity in the Sonoran Desert is about 400 μmol photons/m2/s. According to the graph, what would be the approximate rate of photosynthesis for sun plants that grow in this environment?

d.  Suppose you transplant a sun plant to a shaded forest floor that receives about 100 μmol photons/m2/s. Do you think this plant will grow and thrive? Why or why not? How does the graph help you answer this question?

4a-4 Describe the light-dependent and light-independent reactions of photosynthesis (comparison of products in each) – Ch. 8-3

8. Answer the following questions regarding the Light Dependent reactions:

a.  Where does the energy for the light dependent reactions come from?

b.  Where within the chloroplast do the light dependent reactions take place?

c.  What pigment is contained within this structure?

d.  Define photosystem

e.  The light dependent reactions start in which photosystem?

f.  What are the products of the light dependent reactions?

Comment: **Homework questions** and **trivial questions about basic biological concepts** are off-topic on Biology **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. For more information see our [homework policy](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework).

Comment: So you just decided to copy-and-paste your test here without even *trying* to answer any of the questions? Lovely...

Comment: As far as I know the polyphosphate stores the energy, and the nucleoside is just a flag to know where it delivers the energy to.

Comment: It's fine to ask us to answer your homework, under two conditions. One, *explain what you have done so far to answer it*. Two, *expose one task per question only*.

Answer (score 1):

The energy is "stored" in every bond. The primary bonds that break are either the first and second phosphate or the second and third phosphate creating AMP or ADP.

The middle letter stands for Mono, Di or Tri (meaning 1, 2 or 3 phosphates).

Comment: Please read our [homework policy](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) before answering questions like this.